# How to install rpm-python binding to python3?

Tags: centos, python, rpm, python3

I have python2.6.6(default) and python3.8 installed on Centos 6.10.

Current rpm-python version is 4.8.0.59.

```
Default content of rpm-python:

/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/__init__.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/_rpmbmodule.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/_rpmmodule.so
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/transaction.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/transaction.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/transaction.pyo
```

Is it possible to install rpm-python to Python3.8 path usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages?

Comment: please do not ask twice https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649758/how-to-install-rpm-python-binding-to-python3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have enough points to comment on your question to ask for more info, so I have to use the answer.

1. Have you tried checking if `rpm-python` is in `/usr/local/lib64`?
2. I do not know if you think that `rpm-python` is the same as `python`. In case you did not know, it is *not* version `4.8.0.59` of the "regular" `python` package.

Comment: I am using 32bit Centos 6.10, the rpm 4.8.0.59 in installed at usr/lib/rpm.  I know rpm-python is not a regular python package. That's why I am looking for any options to make it work on Python3, so that I can import rpm and manipulate RPM packages and databases.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I thought that package (`rpm-python`) was only for 64bit? I could be mistaken, though. Anyway, you could try to relocate the package with the command `# rpm -qpi packagename-1.2.3.4 | head -1`, then `rpm -ivh --prefix=/path/to/new/destination packagename-1.2.3.4` and verify with `# rpm -ql packagename-1.2.3.4`.

Comment: $ rpm -qpi rpm-python-4.8.0-59.el6.i686.rpm | head -1
Name        : rpm-python                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
$ rpm -ivh --prefix=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages rpm-python-4.8.0-59.el6.i686.rpm 
error: package rpm-python is not relocatable

Comment: It appears that the package, unfortunately, cannot be installed to another location, then. In theory, appending `--installroot` could solve your issue, but the problem is that the packages usually install to several locations in your fs and that could easily become a true headache to get it to work as it's supposed to :/ Sorry I couldn't be of more help.